# Map URI /foo to Tomcat /

Tags: apache, tomcat, url-rewriting

I have the following situation.

Apache with mod_jk connected to a Tomcat. The Applications Root context is /

What I try to do is the following

Map the URI /foo/ to the application root / 
www.domain.com/foo/ should then show the webapp.

I tried several RewriteRules but it all ends up with a 404 from the Tomcat. Is there a way to
"hide" the /foo/ URI so Tomcat gets a request for / ?

TIA
Izac

Answer (score 0):

You should post your config so we know what went wrong, but

```
ProxyPass / http://www.domain.com/foo
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.domain.com/foo
```

Using [proxy reverse](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/TomcatReverseProxy).

Comment: Hi Will, thats what I did this weekend, worked so far for me. But one thing left, I wanted that www.domain.com gets rewritten to www.domain.com/foo/ but that setup doesent work I get a redirect loop cause of the ProxyPass. I setup a "hidden" Proxy behind the rewriting. People can type www.domain.com it gets rewritten to www.domain.com/foo/ and the second proxy does a ProxyPass /foo/ www.domain.com and Tomcat sees /. Kind of dirty but works.